# Why can we use arrow with pointer?

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I know that the arrow operator `->` is used to dereference objects, but I'm quite confused with its usage on this piece of code from Visual Studio .net framework:

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (txtDisplay->Text->Contains("-")){ //this could be phrased like (*txtDisplay).Text, why does the 'Text', a data member could contain a method named 'Contains()', and if 'Text' is not a data member but rather a class object, why can we assign a value into just like the line next after.
        txtDisplay->Text = txtDisplay->Text->Remove(0, 1); //in here we have assign a value of 'Text' and because of that i assumed 'Text' was a data member
    }
    else {
        txtDisplay->Text = "-" + txtDisplay->Text;
    }
}
```

And another question, what's the main purpose of allocating objects in the heap, as I assume the object `txtDisplay` is in the heap since it's a pointer?

Comment: Not all pointers are on the heap. Pointers are just a form of indirection -- but where it lives can be anywhere (heap, stack, static memory, shared memory, etc). That said, this is *not* true C++. The `T^` syntax is a Microsoft extension for managed pointers AFAIK -- which means that `Object^` and `EventArgs^` will be managed objects. I'm not familiar with where they actually live with this extension, but I'd assume this is on the heap.

Comment: @Human-Compiler txtdisplay is an object right? Text is an object too or a data member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing C++ with the .NET framework and its C++ extensions.

The `txtDisplay` object has a `Text` property which is likely a `System::String^` which means it's a managed object. So you can 'assign' values to a managed object much like you can assign values to any other assignable type or that have the assignment operator overloaded.

For example, in .NET C++ you can do something like the following:

```
System::String^ SomeFunction(int i) {
    return i.ToString();
}
```

Obviously, the `int` type is a basic type that does not have any member methods; however, since you're using .NET, essentially you're utilizing a pseudo-C++ compiler that actually complies the C++ code into .NET which is then executed via the .NET runtime, which runs bytecode and not pure assembly (which is what traditional C++ is compiled to).

So that's why you can assign to the `Text` member.

Regarding whether the objects are allocated in the heap or the stack, that's really up to the .NET compiler/interpreter, but according to what I've read in documentation, there's a good chance it will be in the heap and not the stack, due to its reference counting and garbage collection. I should note that this is purely for the .NET framework and *not* regarding what would happen if you used ISO/ANSI C++.

It's best to think of .NET C++ like C# with C++-like syntax, and not like ISO C++ as they are really different things; yes you can use ISO C++ in .NET C++, but doing so can result in odd and unexpected behavior due to how the .NET CLR works versus a 'normal' C++ application running in a specific environment.

Comment: @RenzCarillo .. I've dissected the .NET framework on an assembly level, and used C and C++ for over 20 years; it comes with the territory ;)